# How to compute the Kronecker sum with Ilnumerics matrix?

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix, ilnumerics

I have result in this matrix

**M matrix**

```
0   2   8   10  6   8
2   0   10  8   8   6
8   10  0   2   5   7
10  8   2   0   7   5
6   8   5   7   0   2
8   6   7   5   2   0
```

This M Matrix is obtain with this 2 matrix A & B

**A matrix**

```
0   8   6
8   0   5
6   5   0
```

**B matrix**

```
0   2
2   0
```

It seems that the result in the matrix M is the Kronecker sum of the matrices A and B

The wikipedia article [Matrix addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition) indicates: The Kronecker sum is different from the direct sum but is also denoted by ⊕. It is defined using the Kronecker product ⊗ and normal matrix addition. If A is n-by-n, B is m-by-m the Kronecker sum is defined by:

[image]

In C#, is it possible to calculate the Kronecker sum with Ilnumerics function ?

Comment: No such function in ILNumerics yet. You can contribute it or register the issue as feature request in the bugtracker: http://ilnumerics.net/mantis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at Math.NET open source project?

http://www.mathdotnet.com/

[Kronecker sum](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Generic/Matrix%601.htm)